# A question on popularization of math: inspiring the beauty of mathematics while making New Year's wishes

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, popular-math

Many fellow students of mine today shared by various means the following picture:

[image: http://media.techeblog.com/images/happy-new-year-equation.jpg].

I was told that this picture is supposed to communicate the beauty of math in a funny way, but I really can't see this point (as the math content of the picture is very trivial).

> Did any mathematical educator [or can you] find a better (*) way to
>   make New Year's wishes (or Christmas wishes)  *mathematically* (in a
>   sense)?
>
> (*) that is, more sophisticated and *really* useful to communicate the beauty
>   of math to students in a fun way.
>
> **Note**: I am *not* searching for a difficult integral whose solution somehow shows up the words "Happy New Year" or anything like that, but for
>   something ***conceptually*** interesting and somehow related to making
>   wishes.

Comment: Personally, I don't find this stuff either funny or beautiful. And making the mathematics more sophisticated isn't likely to improve either the humour or the aesthetics. Surely there are much better ways to increase students' interest in mathematics.

Comment: @bubba If by "this stuff" you mean things like the one in the picture, I agree. This is why I'm searching for something substantially more conceptual and insightful that is *somehow* related to New Year's wishes.